# Simplifying Fourier transform of a complicated function

Tags: evaluation

I would like to evaluate the following expression but takes too much time. I would be greatly appreciate for any comments to make it fast.

```
Clear[a, b];

FullSimplify[
 FourierTransform[
  Exp[-1/2 (1 - s) (a^2 + b^2)]*(α4 1/2 Sqrt[
       6] (1/Sqrt[2] (a + I b))^4 - α1 α4 1/(2 Sqrt[
          6]) (1/Sqrt[2] (a + I b))^3 (-(a^2 + b^2)/2 + 
        4) + α2 α4 1/(2 Sqrt[3]) (1/
          Sqrt[2] (a + I b))^2 ((a^2 + b^2)^2/8 - 2(a^2 + b^2) + 
        6) + α4^2 1/
       24 ((a^2 + b^2)^6/16 - 2 (a^2 + b^2)^3 + 18 (a^2 + b^2)^2 - 
        48 (a^2 + b^2) + 24) + α2 1/
       Sqrt[2] (1/Sqrt[2] (a + I b))^2 - α1 α2 1/
       Sqrt[2] (1/Sqrt[2] (a + I b)) (-(a^2 + b^2)/2 + 
        2) + α2^2 ((a^2 + b^2)^2/8 - (a^2 + b^2) + 
        1) + α2 α4 1/(2 Sqrt[3]) Conjugate[
        1/Sqrt[2] (a + I b)]^2 ((a^2 + b^2)^2/8 - 2 (a^2 + b^2) + 
        6) + α1 (1/
         Sqrt[2] (a + I b)) - α1^2 (-(a^2 + b^2)/2 + 
        1) - α1 α2 1/Sqrt[2] Conjugate[
       1/Sqrt[2] (a + I b)] (-(a^2 + b^2)/2 + 
        2) - α1 α4 1/(2 Sqrt[6]) Conjugate[
        1/Sqrt[2] (a + I b)]^3 (-(a^2 + b^2)/2 + 4) + 
     1 + α1 Conjugate[1/Sqrt[2] (a + I b)] + α2 1/
       Sqrt[2] Conjugate[
        1/Sqrt[2] (a + I b)]^2 + α4 1/(2 Sqrt[6]) Conjugate[
        1/Sqrt[2] (a + I b)]^4), {a, b}, {x, y}], {-1 < s < 1}]
```

Comment: Is your `α1` to `α4` real or complex?

Comment: @ Leo Fang, they are real.

Answer (score 2):

Check if CUDALink is supported on your system.

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
CUDAQ[]
```

If return True use CUDAFourier and CUDAInverseFourier function.

Comment: The OP is doing a *symbolic* Fourier transform with `FourierTransform`. `CUDAFourier` does a discrete *numerical* transform like `Fourier`.

Comment: : CUDA was not able to find a valid CUDA driver in my system. @ Simon Woods you are right it finds the discrete Fourier transform

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficiently faster now by modifying

Clear[a, b];

Assuming[$-1<s<1$ && $\{a, b, \alpha1, \alpha 2,\alpha 4, x, y\}$$\in$Reals,

v = Simplify[the expression]

FourierTransform[v, {a, b}, {x, y}]

It is sufficiently faster now.